# How to combine sha hashes?

Tags: go, cryptography

I have ordered chunks of data, each hashed individually with sha256. I want to combine those hashes into one sha256 hash. Should I just feed the hashes into sha256 as data, or is there another way that's better from a math/crypto standpoint? It might seem like a trivial question, but intuitions are often wrong when it comes to crypto.

*edit*: The purpose of this is to form a sort of a blockchain although that term is pretty overloaded these days. It's for integrity purposes, not proof of work. The idea is hash the blocks at the follower nodes, combine the hashes into one on the cluster leader to have a hash representing the chain as a whole, and then prepend that to the new blocks to be hashed.

It's a little odd in that it's a distributed system so "whole chain hash" is usually a little stale so I know what the hash representing the chain, as known to that node, when the block was created at that node, but there could be several blocks that "hook onto the chain" at that particular hash, and then those are ordered and combined into the system hash which gets prepended to new blocks eventually.

I'm using Go, if that matters.

Comment: the question is: to do what ?

Comment: In other words: Do you want to combine the hashes just because you want to combine these or is there a specific use case where you need this combination. What you should do depends on your specific (and unknown) use case. And especially if you ask how to handle it in a cryptographic proper way details about the use case are essential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to recreate the hash of a large payload (e.g. 1GB file) that has been split into chunks (e.g. 10MBs in size), the hash (MD5, SHA-256 etc.) needs to be computed on the entire collection. So using this example, you cannot *add* the 100 chunked hashes to recreate the hash of the original file. However...

You could send 2 values with each chunk:

- the individual chunk's hash (like you are doing now)
- the intermediate hash *state*, as your service sweeps through the file to create each chunk payload: at the beginning and end of the chunk

As the chunks are streamed in, one can verify the seams of the hash state at the end of chunk `N` matches that of the hash state at the beginning of chunk `N+1`.

The final hash state of the final chunk will be the hash for the entire payload.

Why do it like this? Because the hash can be computed in realtime as the file chunks are received - rather as a separate time-consuming process - after all the file chunks have been received.

---

**Edit:** based on comments:

Here's a crude state hash state solution:

Create a large random file (100MB):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=large.bin bs=1048576 count=100
```

Using an external tool to verify hash:

```
$ shasum -a 256 large.bin 
4cc76e41bbd82a05f97fc03c7eb3d1f5d98f4e7e24248d7944f8caaf8dc55c5c  large.bin
```

Running this [playground code](https://play.golang.org/p/C1DrwdJX3wK) on the above file.

```
...
...
...
offset: 102760448   hash: 8ae7928735716a60ae0c4e923b8f0db8f33a5b89f6b697093ea97f003c85bb56  state: 736861032a24f8927fc4aa17527e1919aba8ea40c0407d5452c752a82a99c06149fd8d35000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006200000
offset: 103809024   hash: fbbfd2794cd944b276a04a89b49a5e2c8006ced9ff710cc044bed949fee5899f  state: 73686103bdde167db6a5b09ebc69a5abce51176e635add81e190aa64edceb280f82d6c08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006300000
offset: 104857600   hash: 4cc76e41bbd82a05f97fc03c7eb3d1f5d98f4e7e24248d7944f8caaf8dc55c5c  state: 73686103c29dbc4aaaa7aa1ce65b9dfccbf0e3a18a89c95fd50c1e02ac1c73271cfdc3e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006400000
```

the final hash matches.

Trying with an offset and intermediate hash-state. The file will be `seeked` to this offset, resuming the hash calculation from that point:

```
$ ./hash -o 102760448 -s "736861032a24f8927fc4aa17527e1919aba8ea40c0407d5452c752a82a99c06149fd8d35000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006200000"
offset:  103809024  hash: fbbfd2794cd944b276a04a89b49a5e2c8006ced9ff710cc044bed949fee5899f  state: 73686103bdde167db6a5b09ebc69a5abce51176e635add81e190aa64edceb280f82d6c08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006300000
offset:  104857600  hash: 4cc76e41bbd82a05f97fc03c7eb3d1f5d98f4e7e24248d7944f8caaf8dc55c5c  state: 73686103c29dbc4aaaa7aa1ce65b9dfccbf0e3a18a89c95fd50c1e02ac1c73271cfdc3e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006400000
```

we get the same final hash as before.

Note: this does expose the hash internal state, so be mindful of the [security implications](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) this may entail. With a large chunk-size, this should not be an issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that many hashing libraries do not support capturing or restoring intermediate state, so you'll probably have to modify an existing piece of code or implement the hashing algorithm by hand. (Great answer, readers may just assume that this is easy.)

Comment: I think this may be what I'm looking for. Do you know how large the hash state is for sha256?

Comment: 32 bytes (for SHA-256 this happens to be the same size as the final hash, but that isn't universal)

Comment: I'll update the answer with on how to resume hash summing, after lunch....

Comment: Looks like this can be done in Go since it implements `encoding.BinaryMarshaler` and `encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler` to marshal and unmarshal the internal state of the hash: https://golang.org/src/crypto/sha256/sha256.go#L161

Comment: @Eloff yes... but there's a catch. Unfortunately the `digest` struct is not public (lowercase `d`). And `sha256.New()` returns the _interface_ `hash.Hash` - and _not_ the `digest` value directly. So one would need to copy the digest source into their own project to be able to invoke the binary marshalers. Doable, but more involved than I had anticipated.

Comment: Actually it looks easier than that, I had a second look, what you would need to do is cast the returned hash.Hash interface to `encoding.BinaryMarshaler` and `encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler`, this is allowed for stdlib hashers according to: https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash

Comment: @Eloff interesting! I've update the answer with a working example including this discovery.

Comment: this construction seems unnecessarily weak (from a crypto PoV), I'd recommend using something like a merkle tree.  exposing internal state like this will "break" various hash schemes.  the finalisation/output function of SHA2 just concatenates the internal state variables so is probably safe, but this would break SHA3.  I'd also recommend looking at HMACs and their attacks if you care about integrity/authenticity

Answer (score 4):

> edit: The purpose of this is to form a sort of a blockchain although
>   that term is pretty overloaded these days. It's for integrity
>   purposes, not proof of work. The idea is hash the blocks at the
>   follower nodes, combine the hashes into one on the cluster leader to
>   have a hash representing the chain as a whole, and then prepend that
>   to the new blocks to be hashed.

this look like a `merkle tree`

https://brilliant.org/wiki/merkle-tree/

> A Merkle tree is a hash-based data structure that is a generalization
>   of the hash list. It is a tree structure in which each leaf node is a
>   hash of a block of data, and each non-leaf node is a hash of its
>   children. Typically, Merkle trees have a branching factor of 2,
>   meaning that each node has up to 2 children.
>
> Merkle trees are used in distributed systems for efficient data
>   verification. They are efficient because they use hashes instead of
>   full files. Hashes are ways of encoding files that are much smaller
>   than the actual file itself. Currently, their main uses are in
>   peer-to-peer networks such as Tor, Bitcoin, and Git.

Have a look to that implementation https://github.com/cbergoon/merkletree

Answer (score 3):

Try taking your SHA256 hashes that you have already and put them in a string.  Then hash that string using SHA256 or the Algorithm of your choice.  Alternatively, you could string together your original chucks of data and then hash that.  But I think its quicker and cleaner to just "hash the hashes".